# Excessive Case Statement Help - SQL Server

Tags: sql, case

I'm supposed to answer this for class, and it's tricky (for me)

Write a SELECT query to output the name of all employees with the name of their supervisor. If the employee has no supervisor, the supervisor name column should contain the text 'No Supervisor'.

The primary key field in my db is the employeeid and they are provided with names, and each student also has a supervisorid

The table for this is shown below (sorry for the layout):

```
employeeid  lastname  firstname   salary  supervisorid
1           Stolz     Ted         25000   NULL
2           Boswell   Nancy       23000   1
3           Hargett   Vincent     22000   1
4           Weekley   Kevin       22000   3
5           Metts     Geraldine   22000   2
6           McBride   Jeffrey     21000   2
7           Xiong     Jay         20000   3
```

I was wondering how I could go about this statement without using the case statement to apply each of the 7 students with:

```
when concat(firstname,' ',lastname)='Nancy Boswell' then 'Ted Stolz'
```

In larger tables this would simply be a HUGE statement, is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've now tried this:

```
  SELECT
         EMP1.employeeid as 'employee',
         EMP2.supervisorid as 'manager'
  FROM
         employee EMP1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
         employee EMP2
  ON
        emp1.employeeid = emp2.supervisorid;
```

However, I am seeing duplicate fields, for some reason employee 2 and 3 are appearing twice, meaning there are 9 fields showing instead of 7.

Also, I need to display their names, not their id's does that mean I need to join the join that i've already done to the employee name ? How would I do this?

Thanks for the feedback guys!

Comment: You will need to join on the same table twice, hope that gives you a hint

Comment: Can you also show a sample of what you have tried as you are learning, we cant just GIVE the answer without some effort offered.

Comment: You are right about not using a big case statement on this. The answer is much easier. Follow @Matt's advice.

Comment: Search for `SQL JOIN`, and then either `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` (depending on which SQL database you're using).

Comment: I'm using sql server management studio, and yes the case statement looks horrendously unnecessary now. I edited my original post if you want to look at that, I understand it fully it's just I don't know to display the syntax to add another join. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the table with itself based on the supervisorId. This might be strange if you are new to SQL but it is very common to do. You tell with SQL to add the row of the supervisor to the row of the employee via its primary key.

```
  SELECT
         *
  FROM
         EMPLOYEES EMP1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
         EMPLOYEES EMP2
  ON     
         -- make link between tables here
```

Note that the above query is not 100% correct / complete, its an indication. The LEFT OUTER JOIN statement makes the employees without supervisor have null values for the supervisor, otherwise the whole record would be left out.

Comment: We typically don't just post complete answers for homework questions here, as all that does is teach the poster how to copy/paste.

Comment: I see your point. But it depends on the person, I learn much faster by getting straight answers than to come up with some myself when it comes to getting to know the basic knowledge. I'll edit it to be a bit more abstract.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the person. :-) Providing copy/paste answers to homework questions simply throws away any educational value to the question, other than teaching the user that if they ask here someone will do the work for them to copy and paste. You don't "learn faster" by having someone else do all the work for you - all you learn is how easy it is to have someone else do all the work for you, and you get very proficient in using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.

Comment: Much better answer, IMO. :-) +1.

Comment: @KenWhite Almost everything on this site is just complete answers to questions, so long as people put effort into asking decent questions, it doesn't matter if it's homework or not. In fact, I'd rather give complete answers to people on their homework than to people who are getting paid to do work.

Comment: @GoatCO: Agreed, with two notes. 1) The question is not a direct request for completion of a homework assignment - the recipient learns nothing, and the end result is lots more low quality questions here by people looking for copy/paste answers to homework questions, and 2) that the poster actually *put effort into something first*. I see no benefit to future readers here for copy/paste homework questions with copy/paste answers to them, and lots of reasons not to have them, including encouraging other LQ questions and the fact that I may end up working with a copy/paste coder in the future.

Comment: I used your approach to if you look at my original post, thanks for the current feedback. As I'm wanting to take SQL further I really want to learn how to do this, and that will mean me studying and learning for myself, I'm just using this as a way for people who are already knowledgeable to point me in the right direction so I can save time and not stress out too much! Could you see my edited original post too if that's possible? Thanks :)

Comment: seems ok @user2334014